# Shortcut in calculating examples of elements of a given order?

Tags: number-theory

My question is:

> Find all possible orders of elements of the group of units $G_{31}$. Give an example of an elememt of each possible order.

I did the question, but I felt I did it a long way. As $31$ is prime, elements of $G_{31} = \{1, 2, \cdots 30\}$. Possible orders are divisiors of $\varphi(31) = 30 = 1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30$. So, to get an example of each element, I litterally went through all elements checking their orders. Like, I didn't have to go through ALL of them because I noticed after a while if I was going to get the order I wanted or if I wasn't, but it still took a while calculating all of this.

Is there a shortcut to finding all this? So, I think I'm asking, is there a way to solve

$$a^{10} \equiv 1 \mod 31,$$
$$a^{15} \equiv 1 \mod 31$$
$$\mathrm{etc}$$
without trial and error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $31$ is prime, the ring $\mathbb Z/31\mathbb Z$ is a field and henc its multiplicative group $G_{31}$ is cyclic. Therefore, you can find an element $g$ of order $30$. Then the elements of order $d|30$ are precisely the $g^k$ with $\gcd(k,30)=\frac{30}d$.

Comment: So, to put it in other words, I first find the primitive element, $g$. Then, lets say I want an element of order $10$, I do $30/10 = 3$, and so I find $k$ such that $\gcd(k,g) = 1$ and $\gcd(k,30) = 3$ and then just do $g^3$?

Comment: It is not always easy to find such a $g$. Sometimes you can create one by combining elements of known low order. Here it is easy to check that $2^5=1$ and $6^6=1$ - the exponents $5$ and $6$ are coprime, so $2\times6=12$ has order $30$. $3$ also turns out to have order $30$.